# plotting an interaction term in moderated regression using MICE imputation

Tags: r, plot, regression, linear-regression, r-mice

I'm using imputed data to test a series of regression models, including some moderation models.

Imputation

```
imp_data <- mice(data,m=20,maxit=20,meth='cart',seed=12345)
```

I then convert this to long format so I can recode / sum variables as needed, beore turning back to mids format

```
impdatlong_mids<-as.mids(impdat_long)
```

Example model:

```
model1 <- with(impdatlong_mids,
               lm(Outcome ~ p1_sex + p2 + p3 + p4
                  + p5+ p6+ p7+ p8+ p9+ p10
                  + p11+ p1_sex*p12+ p1_sex*p13 + p14)
```

in non-imputed data, to create a graphic representation of the significant ineraction, I'd use (e.g.)

```
interact_plot (model=model1, pred = p1_sex, modx = p12)
```

This doesn't work with imputed data / mids objects.
Has anyone plotted an interaction using imputed data, and able to help or share examples?

Thanks

### EDIT: Reproducible example

```
library(tidyverse)
library(interactions)
library(mice)
# library(reprex) does not work with this
set.seed(42)
options(warn=-1)

#---------------------------------------#
# Data preparations

# loading an editing data
d <- mtcars
d <- d %>% mutate_at(c('cyl','am'),factor)

# create missing data and impute it
mi_d <- d
nr_of_NAs <- 30
for (i in 1:nr_of_NAs) {
  mi_d[sample(nrow(mi_d),1),sample(ncol(mi_d),1)] <- NA
}


mi_d <- mice(mi_d, m=2, maxit=2)
#---------------------------------------#
# regressions

#not imputed
lm_d <- lm(qsec ~ cyl*am + mpg*disp, data=d)

#imputed dataset
lm_mi <- with(mi_d,lm(qsec ~ cyl*am + mpg*disp))
lm_mi_pool <- pool(lm_mi)

#---------------------------------------#
# interaction plots
# not imputed

#continuous
interactions::interact_plot(lm_d, pred=mpg,modx=disp, interval=T,int.width=0.3)


#categorical
interactions::cat_plot(lm_d, pred = cyl, modx = am)
```

[image: Sample continuous and categorical plots]

```
#---------------------------------------#
# interaction plots
# imputed

#continuous
interactions::interact_plot(lm_mi_pool, pred=mpg,modx=disp, interval=T,int.width=0.3)
# Error in model.frame.default(model) : object is not a matrix

#categorical
interactions::cat_plot(lm_mi_pool, pred = cyl, modx = am)
# Error in model.frame.default(model) : object is not a matrix
```

The problem seems to be that neither interact_plot, cat_plot or any other available package  allows for (at least categorical) interaction plotting with objects of class mipo or pooled regression outputs.

Comment: can you make your example more reproducible with some data? what is `impdat_long`/ how did you create it?

Comment: added a reproducible example. Before the edit is approved or in case it is not accepted, the code is also available in here:
https://gist.github.com/samuelsaari/a3be910f57469c7a001ceab9ffef6d6c

Answer (score 3):

I am using the walking data from the mice package as an example. One way to get the interaction plot (well version of one type of interaction plot) is to use the gtsummary package. Under the hood it will take the `model1` use `pool()` from mice to average over the models and then use a combo of `tbl_regression()` and `plot()` to output a plot of the coefficients in the model. The `tbl_regression()` function is what is calling the `pool()` function.

```
library(mice)
library(dplyr)
library(gtsummary)
imp_data <- mice(mice::walking,m=20,maxit=20,meth='cart',seed=12345)

model1 <- with(imp_data,
     lm(age ~ sex*YA))


model1 %>% 
      tbl_regression() %>% 
      plot()
```

[image: plot from mice model]

Answer (score 0):

The package emmeans allows you to extract interaction effects from a mira object. [Here](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/seminars/interactions-r/#s5) is a gentle introduction. After that, the interactions can be plotted with appropriate ggplot. This example is for the categorical variables but could be extended to the continous case - after the emmeans part things get relatively straighforward.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggstance)
library(emmeans)
library(khroma)
library(jtools)


lm_mi <- with(mi_d,lm(qsec ~ gear*carb))

#extracting interaction effects
emcatcat <- emmeans(lm_mi, ~gear*carb)
tidy <- as_tibble(emcatcat)

#plotting
pd <- position_dodge(0.5)

ggplot(tidy, aes(y=gear, x=emmean, colour=carb)) + 
geom_linerangeh(aes(xmin=lower.CL, xmax=upper.CL), position=pd,size = 2) +
geom_point(position=pd,size = 4)+
ggtitle('Interactions') +
labs (x = "aggreageted interaction effect") +
scale_color_bright() +
  theme_nice()
```

this can be extended to a three-way interaction plot with `facet_grid` as long as you have a third categorical interaction term.

[image: Categorical interaction plot]